# How do I fill a 90 by 90 square using Minecraft commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Im trying to build a base for an ice hotel but cant fill the 90x90 floor for it with the fill command. What are the coordinates for a 90x90 square floor on the ground?

Comment: Which corner of your room are going to run the command? +x +z, +x -z, -x +z or -x -z? Do you know how to find out?

Comment: um, im in a flat snow world. im trying to see the x, y, and z coordinates that match that array and the commands to go with the coordinates. remember, im only looking for a 90x90 floor that replaces the surface block(snow) with a new block(ice). So, could you find the research for that?

Comment: and no. i dont know how to find out?

Comment: Are you asking us about coordinates in your world? We're not omniscient. Just press F3 yourself.

Comment: what does omniscient mean?

Comment: and yes i am asking about coordinates

Comment: Omniscient means All-knowing, like in 3rd person of a book you view things as if you are a god or God himself (not trying to throw religion out there) @user224246

Answer (score 2):

You use`/fill` works by giving it two `x y z` locations, which correspond to the two opposite corners of a cuboid.

If you are standing in the center of the place you want to make a floor, the command is `/fill ~-45 ~-1 ~-45 ~45 ~-1 ~15 minecraft:your desired block`.